# I got some errors when I create an header listview on xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

```html
  public class CustomAdapter : BaseAdapter{

 private  const int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
 private const int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;

 private List<String> mData;
 private TreeSet sectionHeader;

 private LayoutInflater mInflater;

 public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
  mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
   .GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
 }

 public void addItem( String item) {
  mData.Add(item);
  NotifyDataSetChanged();
 }

 public void addSectionHeaderItem(String item) {
  mData.Add(item);
  sectionHeader.Add(mData.Count - 1);
  NotifyDataSetChanged();
 }

 public int getItemViewType(int position) {
  return sectionHeader.Contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
 }


 public int getViewTypeCount {
  get{ return 2; }
 }


 public override int Count {
  get {return mData.Count;}
 }


 public override GetItem this[int position] {
  get{ return mData [position]; }
 }
  
 public override long GetItemId(int position) {
  return position;
 } 

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  ViewHolder holder = null;
  int rowType = getItemViewType(position);

  if (convertView == null) {
   holder = new ViewHolder();
   switch (rowType) {
   case TYPE_ITEM:
    convertView = mInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.textViewItemsSeparator, parent);
    holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.textviewHeaderItems);
    break;
   case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
    convertView = mInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.textViewHeaderItems, parent);
    holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.textviewItemsSeparator);
    break;
   }
   convertView.Tag=holder;
  } else {
   holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.Tag as ViewHolder;
  }
  holder.textView.Text=mData[position];

  return convertView;
 }

 public  class ViewHolder:Java.Lang.Object {
  public TextView textView;
 }
```

```html
OnActivityCreated:
mAdapter=new CustomAdapter(this);
   for (int i = 0; i <= items.Count; i++) {
    mAdapter.addItem (items [i].ToString ());
    if (i == 0) {
     mAdapter.addSectionHeaderItem ("Music");
    } else if(i==13) {
     mAdapter.addSectionHeaderItem ("Audio");
    }
   }
   lst.Adapter = new CustomAdapter (Activity, mAdapter);
```

Create your custom adapter for ListView

You must override getViewTypeCount() method. This method returns the number of types of Views that will be created by getView method.

I was trying to create a header listview.

Comment: The Xamarin Android API docs are here: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/root/MonoAndroid-lib.  Try looking up each method you're having trouble with, read the docs for the method, and fix your error.  Simply posting a list of errors here and expecting us to fix them for you isn't cool.

Comment: I have no idea holder.textView.SetText(mData[position]);

Comment: GetItem does not exist...

Answer (score 1):

Set the text using the property of a `TextView`

```
holder.textView.Text = mData[position];
```

Under the hood, Xamarin converts the **C#** `string` to **Java** `CharSequence` and calls `setText` for you.

---

P.S

You have to look at the documentation! It is a must when you're a beginner.

Comment: Updated my code at bottom.ublic override GetItem this[int position] {
   get{ return mData [position]; }
  }

ex:BaseAdapter<TrackModel.Track>->public override TrackModel.Track this[int index]
   {
    get{ return _tracks [index]; }
   }

Comment: so Wha't name instead for GetItem